# How to call method of the subclass?

Tags: java, oop

I have a superclass like this:

```
public class GenericUpdate{

//...other stuff...

public String getName(){return null;};

}
```

And a subclasses like this:

```
public class FromFriend extends GenericUpdate {

@Override
public String getName() {return getFriend().getName();}

}
```

or this:

```
public class FromArtist extends GenericUpdate {

@Override
public String getName() {return getArtist().getName();}

}
```

Now,

some other class delivers me a list of `GenericUpdate`

if I iterate on the list and call `GenericUpdate.getName()` I get **null** back from `getName()`

is there a nice solution to avoid this?

Thanks

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

the actual instances of the `GenericUpdate` class are retrieved from Android Intents, they are retrieved like this:

```
    genericUpdate=intent.getParcelableExtra(GENERIC_UPDATE);
```

and they are put in the intent like this:

```
GenericUpdate genericUpdate=((FlowAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);    
//...                        
intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.GENERIC_UPDATE,genericUpdate);
//...
```

Comment: What's the signature of the method? How do you iterate on it? Please post relevant parts.

Comment: If your `GenericUpdate` class always needs subclassing, make it abstract and `getName()` method abstract also.

Comment: The method of the subclass *is* invoked. (All methods are virtual in Java.) If you get `null` back I suggest you try to see if `getFriend()` or `getArtist()` has a `null` name.

Comment: How you initialise your objects contained in the GenericUpdate list?

Comment: Don't return null?...

Comment: @LisaAnne, please print `genericUpdate.getClass().toString()` inside the loop and tell us what the output is.

Comment: @aioobe I get this `class com.mypackage.javaclasses.GenericUpdate`

Comment: Then those objects are not instances of FromFriend or FromArtist and you shouldn't be surprised that FromFriend.getName and FromArtist.getName aren't called.

Comment: @aioobe indeed... :-(((

Comment: @aioobe if you want to post an answer I will accept it, thanks a lot aiobe

Comment: From your edits above, you should make sure that the value being passed to the `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()` accepts instances of `FromFriend` or `FromArtist` and NOT `GenericUpdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods in Java are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function), so you can't "accidentally" call the base class method on an object of a subclass.

To see the runtime type of the objects in your list, you can for instance print `genericUpdate.getClass().toString()`.

If this gives `class com.mypackage.javaclasses.FromFriend` then `getFriend.getName()` most likely return `null`. If this gives `class com.mypackage.javaclasses.GenericUpdate` your objects are not of the right subtypes and there should be no surprise that the subclass implementations of `getName` are not called.

**(Turns out it was the latter in this case.)**

So if you have control over the code of the `GenericUpdate` class you can make sure this situation is avoided by making `GenericUpdate` abstract. (Note that an abstract class can still have fields.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need interface?

```
public interface GenericUpdate{

//...other stuff...

public String getName();

}

public class FromFriend implements GenericUpdate {

@Override
public String getName() {return getFriend().getName();}

}
```

or this:

```
public class FromArtist implements GenericUpdate {

@Override
public String getName() {return getArtist().getName();}

}
```

Then no one could add a non valid object to your list, and there should be always a valid implementation of this method if you have an instance of object implementing this interface.

The interfaces role is exactly that, to tell others what they should implement, so you can have some abstact algorithm that uses this kind of objects that implement it.

You can't instantiate pure intercface, you need to implement it, and this guarantess you, that every object will have implementation, that should be valid.

Comment: Making class abstract also would help.

Comment: Good point!+1! The problem is that I cannot make the `GenericUpdate` an `interface` because `GenericUpdate` contains some data

Comment: Changing the base class to an interface or making the base class abstract won't help. The subclass method *is* already invoked, and whatever the reason for this is, won't change by going through an interface or abstract class.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou indeed it would, but please see my comment to Krzysztof

Comment: @aioobe if it is so aiube, why do I get null? :-(((

Comment: Most likely because `getArtist().getName()` or `getFriend().getName()` returns null. (Let me know if this is indeed the case, and I can write it down in a proper answer.)

Comment: @aioobe making class abstract will help to make sure that methods of concrete class instances are called. Now, `GenericUpdate` can be instantiated directly.

Comment: No, it won't make a difference. All methods are virtual. You can't "accidentally" call the base class method through an object of a subtype.

Comment: @Lisa GenericUpdate sounds like an interface...you can look at it this way....there are several classes like FromFriend, FromArtist, FromPhilosopher, FromGod....etc which all implement the GenericUpdate interface...so these classes hold the actual data....Interface is just telling us how to interact with these classes...so getName is a method to interact with these classes....if i just blankly call getName on any object implementing the interface...it will call the getName implementation of that Class....

Comment: @aioobe Sure, but now we cannot see why null is returned, because `getName()` is called on `GenericUpdate` which is instantiated by itself, e. g. by `GenericUpdate gu = new GenericUpdate()`, or because it returns null member variable of concrete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

From your statement above, the class `GenericUpdate` has a method `getName()` which returns null. If you observe correctly, this class can also be instantiated. Therefore, if you have a list of `GenericUpdate` classes, they will always return null, since the `getName()` method always returns `null`.

If you don't want your `Generic` class to be instantiated, you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericUpdate{
    public abstract String getName();
}
```

Then, you can now extend your classes the same way you've done.
Now, to use the `GenericUpdate`'s `getName()` method, you have to do something like:

```
GenericUpdate fromFriend = new FromFriend();
fromFriend.getName();
```

This will never return null for GenericUpdate as long as the `getFriend().getName();` method in your implementation has a value, and is not null.

Another alternative is to use Krzysztof Cichocki answer above.

Comment: Yes, I agree... but what if I cannot make it and interface or abstract class because it contains some data?

Comment: What do you mean by the class contains some data? Normally, an abstract class is one that can have it's method defined and therefore, by calling a method implemented in this class from the subclass, you will be able to use the method, unless it's abstract where you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Abstract classes can have data.

Comment: I needs some of the fields not abstract, they need to be initialized to some value

Comment: The best way to use the `GenericUpdate` class is to use it's subclasses as the passed value. DON'T explicitly instantiate a `GenericUpdate` but instantiate an object of it's subclass.